# How to query android sqlite database and store results in a string that can be displayed in a webview?

Tags: android, html, sqlite, webview, cursor

I've read tons of articles and books on the subject. For the most part a have a decent grasp of android development. But I'm having a hard time incorporating a database. I have a database called "Library". In the database I have a table called "Books". And in the "Books" table I have 3 columns "id, Book, Chapter". I want to reference the Chapter field based off of the Book field for example..."Select Chapter FROM Books WHERE Book ="Genesis1";. The Contents of the Chapter field is pure html so I would like to save the output of my query to a string and then put that string into a webview, the purpose being so that I can create a search a search box or widget to enable the user to search all book content. Here's what I have so far:

Constants.java

```
package watchtower.library.org;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public interface Constants extends BaseColumns {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Books";

public static final String Book = "book";
public static final String Chapter = "chapter";
}
```

LibraryData.java

```
package watchtower.library.org;

import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;
import static watchtower.library.org.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static watchtower.library.org.Constants.Book;
import static watchtower.library.org.Constants.Chapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class LibraryData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WatchtowerLibrary.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public LibraryData(Context ctx){
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +"( +_ID" 
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Book
            + " INTEGER," + Chapter + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Genesis1.java

```
package watchtower.library.org;

import static watchtower.library.org.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static watchtower.library.org.Constants.Chapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Genesis1 extends Activity {
private LibraryData WatchtowerLibrary;
private Cursor getEvents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = WatchtowerLibrary.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Chapter" + "FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE                                                                                                              
Book is Genesis1", null); 
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
}
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scriptures);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());   
}
}
```

And that's where I'm stuck!! lol! I'm probably way off track. I'm greatfull for whatever suggestions you might have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Chapter" + "FROM" + TABLE_NAME + 
"WHERE  Book is Genesis1", null);
```

need to be like this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Chapter FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE                 
Book is Genesis1", null);
```

Guess what is the difference? proper spaces...

Comment: I did what you said and I see your point. However now that I have the query syntax correct, how do I go about referencing the result of the query (which I'm thinking is in the return cursor) into my WebView? As it is eclipse is saying that I'm not using "private Cursor getEvents()" anywhere.